# Injectivity and inverse of the map $A \mapsto A_c$, the map sending a matrix to its companion form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathcal E \subset M_n$ denote the set of matrices such that $e_1$ (standard basis vector) is a cyclic vector for all $A \in \mathcal E$. That is if $A \in \mathcal E$, $\{e_1, Ae_1, \dots, A^{n-1}e_1\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb R^n$. Let us define a map $f: \mathcal E \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ by
\begin{align*}
A \mapsto B^{-1}AB,
\end{align*}
where $B = [e_1, Ae_1, \dots, A^{n-1}e_1]$. Now it is clear the image of $f$ will be a subset of matrices in companion form.

if we let $g : \mathcal E \to f(\mathcal E)$, my goal is to see:

1. Whether $g$ is injective. I was thinking in the wrong way in terms of kernel of $g$ but as pointed out in the comment, $g$ is not linear. But is $g$ injective?
2. If $g$ is injective, we should be able to find an inverse. Is it possible to give an explicit fourmula?

Comment: $f$ is not a linear map, so just saying $f(A)=0\implies A=0$ is not enough to prove $f$ is injective...